# New powercord for MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I am considering going on eBay to try and buy a new powercord for my MacBook. I know that phones often advise that you only use the official charger, so I was wondering if the same warning applied for laptops and if so, I serious I should take the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you should be careful when using a charger that doesn't come with your laptop. Apple's official word on the matter is:

> Make sure the proper wattage adapter for your portable computer is used.
>   Select the appropriate power adapter for your Apple portable computer. You can use a higher wattage power adapter, but you cannot use one with less wattage without potential operating issues. ([here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1713) + discussion [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1335235)).

In the good old days (Powerbooks) we used to get all sorts of odd logic board hassles when using the wrong charger. These days it does mean a slower charging time but it can also mean the (very) rare logic board damage or hardware funkiness.

Answer (score 5):

Apple owns a patent on the magsafe connector and hasn't licensed anyone else to make one, I'd be very wary of buying a third party one if you find one at all.

However, best I can tell a magsafe charger from any macbook seems to work with any other one, but if you get one with less wattage than your original it will charge slower.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about Laptop cables, but I've bought at least 3 camera battery chargers over the years from eBay, each one fused in a puff of smoke when plugged in, tripping my mains fuses.

I bought my 2nd MacBook cable direct from Apple. Expensive, but the peace of mind was worth it!

Incidentally, the '[Apple 60W MagSafe Power Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC461LL/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY)' works fine with my old 13" Black MacBook '4,1'.

Answer (score 2):

Any mag-safe charger from Apple should be fine with a standard MacBook. If you have a MacBook Pro, you'll want the higher-rated charger (85W I think). I doubt there are 'legal' 3rd party ones out there, and to be honest even if I found one I'd avoid it and just stick with official Apple spares.